# Use LIKE %..% with field values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I stumbled into a delicate SQL problem when I needed to use a value from a field inside a LIKE %..% statement.

Example:

```
SELECT t1.Notes, t2.Name
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE t1.Notes LIKE '%t2.Name%'
```

This is only an example from the top of my head to show what I need to do (I know this will not work). I need to use the value of t2.Name inside the LIKE %..%

I guess this is trivial when you know it ;)

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT t1.Notes, 
       t2.Name
  FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Notes LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.Name ,'%')
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Aa I said, it is trivial when you know it. However, I stumbled into the next problem... But I will make a new question. Thank you!

Comment: Any solution for all databases?

Comment: Any Solution to use LIKE %..% with field in IF statement?

Comment: Technically you might want to escape the field in case it has % in it: LIKE CONCAT('%',REPLACE(field,'%','\%'),'%')

Answer (score -8):

```
  SELECT t1.a, t2.b
  FROM t1
  JOIN t2 ON t1.a LIKE '%'+t2.b +'%'
```

because the last answer not work