# MySQL like another field

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have a table with two string columns: Url and ModelId. I need to return records for which Url contains ModelId, something like this:

```
SELECT Id, Url, ModelId WHERE Url like "%ModelId%"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use LIKE %..% with field values in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420554/use-like-with-field-values-in-mysql)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

```
SELECT Id, Url, ModelId 
WHERE Url LIKE CONCAT('%', ModelId, '%')
```

Comment: Technically you might want to escape the field in case it has % in it: LIKE CONCAT('%',REPLACE(field,'%','\%'),'%')

Answer (score 5):

You can not just concat the strings, you must also escape the field from % and _:

```
SELECT Id, Url, ModelId 
WHERE Url LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE(REPLACE(ModelId,'%','\%'),'_','\_'), '%'), '%')
```

Comment: Great point. Question: should you also escape the '\' character?
`REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ModelId,'\\','\\\\'),'%','\%'),'_','\_')`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the query:

```
SELECT Id, Url, ModelId WHERE Url LIKE CONCAT('%', ModelId, '%')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Id, Url, ModelId from <table> WHERE Url like '%' + ModelId + '%'
```

Comment: your query does not make sense.

Comment: since when does `+` work for string concatenation in MySQL?