# MYSQL: one table entries containing matching entries in second table. Any query ideas

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am using two MYSQL tables on has big log strings for example: "this is a sample log entry with 123.456.789 IP address". Also, there is second table that contains list of Ip addresses in each row. I want to check for all the matching Ip addresses in the log entries and get the result as all the entries in log tables with matching IPs.

I have installed Mysql community version 5.7.22 on RHEL server.

Table 1 : log table

```
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| log_id      | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Id          | varchar(30)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| host        | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| external_id | varchar(40)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| message     | varchar(8000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timestamp   | varchar(30)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table 2 : IP table

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ip        | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am using below query :

```
select * from logs where message like '%'ip_table.ip'%';
```

which is giving a syntax error.

Any other ideas to work on this?

Comment: `like concat('%', ip_table.ip, '%');` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL like another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886295/mysql-like-another-field)

Comment: Which column in LOG table stores the IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the syntax error by using `concat()`:

```
select *
from logs l join
     ip_table it
     on l.message like concat('%', it.ip, '%');
```

However, this would match, say, '1.1.1.1' and '1.1.1.10'.

To fix this, you need to take delimiters into account.  Assuming this is always a space:

```
select *
from logs l join
     ip_table it
     on concat(' ', l.message, ' ') like concat('% ', it.ip, ' %');
```

Comment: I am receiving  "Unknown column 'ip_table.ip_value' in 'where clause' ". as the ip_table. I believe we need to use some Join here as these a 2nd table. please do correct me if i am wrong

Comment: anyone any suggestions?

Comment: @DEEPANSHUMARWAH . . . This answer has no `where` clause, so it cannot be generating that error.