# Get a table row if it matches another table row string

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch a row from a table which matches rows from another table without stored procedure  in single query. Is this possible? Let me explain graphically. Suppose I have two tables

- tbl_paragraph
- tbl_keywords

I am trying fetch all the paragraph rows whoch matches all the keyword rows.

**tbl_paragraph**

[image]

**tbl_keyword**

[image]

Here when I will try to fetch paragraphs which matches Keyword tables keyword column. So the result will come like as follows

[image]

Though I have tried a sql

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM tbl_paragraph AS a 
INNER JOIN tbl_keywords b ON a.title LIKE '%b.keyword%'
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Use `a.title LIKE CONCAT('%', b.keyword, '%')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL like another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886295/mysql-like-another-field)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I already saw that post and tried....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `LIKE` here, I would actually suggest using `REGEXP`, which by default is case insensitive:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tbl_paragraph a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_keywords b
              WHERE a.title REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', b.keyword, '[[:>:]]'));
```

The other advantage of using `REGEXP` over `LIKE`, other than the case sensitive problem, is that the former lets us use word boundaries.  As I have written the above query, it would match a keyword `we` only as a standalone word.  That is, it would *not* match `weed` against `we`.  This is equivalent to searching for `\bwe\b` in regular regex lingo.